# IOS - Core data backup in iCloud

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, icloud

I have an iPad app which tracks daily expenses and do some extra stuffs. The app uses core data as data storage mechanism.

I planned to add a feature to back up user's database to iCloud, because

- I planned to convert the app as universal
- To prevent accedential data lose

My current requirement is , the database should be local and most recent back up should be available in iCloud.

1 - Is it posible to backup the whole database to iCloud and map it to the local db?
2 - or is there any other recommended machanisam to achive this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just asking a general question - have a look at the [Using Core Data with iCloud Programming Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/) and come back if you have a more detailed question.